# Folding over a list and counting all occurrences of arbitrarily many unique and unknown entities

Tags: haskell, fold

I am using the `Control.Foldl` library to traverse an arbitrarily long list and counting all occurrences of arbitrarily many unique entities. Ie, the list may be of form

```
[Just "a", Just "b", Just "aab", Nothing, Just "aab"]
```

and I my result should be of form

`[(Just "a",1),(Just "b",1) (Just "aab", 2), (Nothing, 1)]`

Now the issue is I do not have the name of these entities a priori, and I would like to dynamically update the results as I fold.

My problem is that I do not know how to describe this computation in terms of the `Fold a b` data type from `foldl`. Specifically, at each step of the fold I need to traverse the result list and ask if I have seen the current item, but I see no way of describing this using `foldl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the other answers, I'd like to bring your attention to the concept of [monoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid). It's an abstraction for combining a sequence of elements (including 0-length) using an [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property) operation.

In this case, the monoid will be a map of elements to numbers (their count), with the empty element being an empty map and the combining operation merges the two maps, summing values for keys present in both.

```
{-# Language DerivingVia        #-}
{-# Language DerivingStrategies #-}

import Data.Foldable
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Monoid
-- https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monoidal-containers
import Data.Map.Monoidal

newtype CountMap k = CountMap { getCountMap :: M.Map k Int }
  -- (<>)   = M.unionWith (+)
  -- mempty = M.empty
  deriving (Semigroup, Monoid)
  via MonoidalMap k (Sum Int)

  deriving
  stock (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)

singleton :: k -> CountMap k
singleton x = CountMap $ M.singleton x 1

unique :: (Foldable f, Ord k) => f k -> [(k, Int)]
unique = M.toList . getCountMap . foldMap singleton
```

While solutions described using monoids aren't not necessarily the shortest ones, they often express the main idea more clearly and on a higher level than than folds.

Also for structures other than lists, for example trees, combining elements using monoids is more natural (and in some cases more efficient): Each leaf is converted to its corresponding value in the monoid and then the values are combined bottom up.

See also [Monoids and Finger Trees](http://apfelmus.nfshost.com/articles/monoid-fingertree.html).

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
λ> :set -XTupleSections
λ> import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map
λ> Map.fromListWith (+) $ fmap (,1) [Just "a", Just "b", Just "aab", Nothing, Just "aab"]
fromList [(Nothing,1),(Just "a",1),(Just "aab",2),(Just "b",1)]
```

we just map over the list to form a pair of `(x,1)` and then use [fromListWith](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html#v:fromListWith) to build up the `Map`.

```
countOccurences :: (Num a, Ord k) => [k] -> Map.Map k a
countOccurences = Map.fromListWith (+) . fmap (,1)
```

Comment: This solution is good as well, but I'm going to be computing several values, each time I need to traverse the entire list. Hence using foldl.

Answer (score 1):

A fold allows you to traverse a list while keep track of some state. In this case the state you want to keep is the current list of counts of each string seen so far.

Let's model this state as `Map String Int` where `Map` is from `Data.Map.Strict`.

If `m` is our current state, we can perform these operations:

```
findWithDefault 0 str m -- returns the count for string str
                           returns 0 if the string isn't found

insert str count m      -- insert the tuple (str,count) into the map
                           (replaces previous value at key str)

empty                   -- the empty map
```

With these operations, our step function for the fold can look like this:

```
step :: Map String Int -> String -> Map String Int
step m str =
  let count = findWithDefault 0 str m
      m' = insert str (count+1) m
  in m'
```

The complete fold is:

```
countStrings :: [String] -> Map String Int
countStrings strs = foldl step empty strs
```

Note that the use of `Data.Map.Strict` is important here. You want `count+1` to be evaluated eagerly instead of stored as a thunk.

Answer (score 1):

Consider grouping the sorted list by equality, then applying a lambda function to count occurrences,

```
import Data.List

entryCount :: Ord a => [a] -> [(a,Int)]
entryCount = map (\v -> (head v, length v)) . groupBy (==) . sort
```

Hence

```
entryCount [Just "a", Just "b", Just "aab", Nothing, Just "aab"]
[(Nothing,1),(Just "a",1),(Just "aab",2),(Just "b",1)]
```

Comment: This solution is good, but I'm going to be computing several values, each time I need to traverse the entire list. Hence using foldl.